# Redis pub/sub with multiple socket.io instances

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ioredis

I recently upgraded socket.io from v1 to v4 and i found that it's working perfectly when using only with one server and when it's scaled up to multiple instances there is some issue with sharing data in subscriber mode

explanation:

When user 1 connected to server 1, user 2 connected to server 2 and user 1 sends multiple messages to user 2, so in this case sometimes server 1 getting data in subscriber mode and sometimes server 2 getting data from redis so due to this some messages are not sending.

I was using ioredis 5.x.x with node along with socket.io v4 , express to create client in subscriber mode

and in publisher mode i was pushing data from Ruby on rails.

for this kind of issues i found socket.io/redis-adapter and emitter in socket.io documentation but I was not able to create client in subscriber mode

can someone guide me for this..

I tried with ioredis but it's not working as expected with multiple instances